# How is the value of $\lambda$ estimated in Poisson distribution using MLE when the sample is comprised of only 0s?

Tags: poisson-distribution, maximum-likelihood

Imagine we have a sample x = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0) of a Poisson distribution, where $X \sim Po(\lambda)$. The MLE of $\lambda$ is $$\hat{\lambda} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i$$
Therefore, for the sample x = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0), $\hat{\lambda} = 0$. However, by definition of the Poisson distribution $\lambda > 0$.

How is that possible and how is the MLE $\hat{\lambda}$ calculated?

Answer (score 1):

For purposes of maximum likelihood estimation, one should take the parameter space to be closed.

You have $L(\lambda) = \prod_{i=1}^5 \dfrac{\lambda^0 e^{-\lambda}}{0!} = e^{-5\lambda}$ for $\lambda\ge0.$

That is a decreasing function of $\lambda,$ so its global maximum is at the lower endpoint of the parameter space.

Sometimes it seems appalling to see how many people think an MLE is simply a point at which $L\,'=0.$ That neglects the fact that $(1)$ not every critical point is the location of a global maximum, and $(2)$ when a global maximum is at the boundary of the domain, the derivative there need not be $0,$ and $(3)$ there are instances in which the quickest way to find the location of a global maximum does not involve using derivatives at all.

And one may consider a degenerate Poisson distribution that assigns probability $1$ to $\{0\}.$

Comment: I understand that, however, doesn't finding the MLE require you to set the derivative to 0 and then checking whether it's a maximum? So in the case above, when lambda is at the lower end of the boundary but not 0, how would you denote the value of the MLE mathematically?

Comment: @Ivalin : Setting the derivative to zero is not essential to the concept of MLE. It is merely one technique that is often used. The MLE for $\theta$ based on an i.i.d. sample from the uniform distribution on $[0,\theta]$ is not at a point where the derivative is zero, and neither is the MLE considered in this present problem. Go back to your calculus textbook and read the part about endpoint extrema. And also, extrema can be at places where the derivative is undefined, as with the absolute value function.